# PyQt setText not rendering text properly in MacOs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am creating an application using PyQt5 (pythyon 3.7 , MacOs X)
When I modify the text in a textbox using the instruction

```
self.line_main.setText(final_text)
```

from a function (which is connected to a push button)
The new text does not render properly in the textbox (see screenshot) and both the old and new text are overlapping in a strange way. 
An over-simplified code to illustrate the problem is this one:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(200, 200))
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt test")
        self.line_main = QLineEdit(self)
        self.line_main.move(20,20)

        bt_upperCase = QPushButton('Upper Case', self)
        bt_upperCase.move(20, 60)
        bt_upperCase.clicked.connect(self.click_upCase)

    def click_upCase(self):
        final_text=self.line_main.text().upper()
        self.line_main.setText(final_text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

screenshot of mini-app, with 're' as input as 'RE' as output

[image]

The same thing may happen for labels, although at times, only the old text is visible, and I need to select the text with the mouse or resize the main window to 'refresh' the textbox and see the new value.

The problem does not happen if I run the code in a PC, only in  MacOs (tested in High Sierra and Mojave with identical results)

Some weird behaviours are:

- If position the textbox at the (0,0) position in the main window, which is not very practical, then the setText functions correctly. In some other locations of the box, too, but only if it is very close to the top-left corner, and no other element is near.
- If I modify the textbox value at the initialization of the main window, then it renders correctly in all cases, The problem appears when you try to do it from a function (after clicking a button, for instance), like in the code attached.
  The problem does not happen if I run the code in a PC, only in  MacOs (tested in High Sierra and Mojave with identical results)
- If position the textbox at the (0,0) position in the main window, (which is not very practical), then the setText functions correctly. In some other locations of the box, too, but only if it is very close to the top-left corner, and no other element is near.

Does anyone have a guess why this may happen, and how could it be solved?

**UPDATE.** 
The problem *dissapears* if i run the code with python 3.6 in a conda installation (PyQt version 5.9.2). Still very intrigued to know what caused the problem.

Comment: what is your PyQt5 version?

Comment: PyQt5 is version 5.11.2

Comment: I think it's a problem with a driver on your computer, try updating PyQt5 5.11.3, have you tried on other computers with the same version of Mac OS?

Comment: I've tried in 2 computers, with high sierra and Mojave, respectively. I just updated to PyQt5 5.11.3 but had same result.